# java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, sharedpreferences

i am using shared preferences to store the user name and password in order to achieve onetime user authentication. I am encrypting and storing the data in shared pref file. Again i am decrypting them and validating the values every time the user open the application. It is working fine until the App is running on background.

If the user close the app from background i am again getting the login screen asking to input the user credentials.
Below is the error:

```
W/System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA

W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(CipherSpi.java:275)

W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(CipherSpi.java:379)

W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:661)

W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:621)
```

Below is my encryption Algorithm. I am calling the genereteKey() method before comitting the data in to shared pref file and encrypting the data then commiting the data.

```
    private final static String RSA = "RSA";
public static PublicKey uk;
public static PrivateKey rk;

public static void generateKey() throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA);

    gen.initialize(512, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keyPair = gen.generateKeyPair();
    uk = keyPair.getPublic();
    rk = keyPair.getPrivate();
}

private static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey pubRSA) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubRSA);
    return cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
}

public final static String encrypt(String text) {
    try {
        return byte2hex(encrypt(text, uk));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public final static String decrypt(String data) {
    try {
        return new String(decrypt(hex2byte(data.getBytes())));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] src) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rk);
    return cipher.doFinal(src);
}

public static String byte2hex(byte[] b) {
    String hs = "";
    String stmp = "";
    for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n++) {
        stmp = Integer.toHexString(b[n] & 0xFF);
        if (stmp.length() == 1) hs += ("0" + stmp);
        else
            hs += stmp;
    }
    return hs.toUpperCase();
}


public static byte[] hex2byte(byte[] b) {
    if ((b.length % 2) != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("hello");
    byte[] b2 = new byte[b.length / 2];
    for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n += 2) {
        String item = new String(b, n, 2);
        b2[n / 2] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(item, 16);
    }
    return b2;
}
```

Comment: Which line of *your code* is the error coming from?

Comment: i am getting the exception whenever it reaches the below line in decrypt method
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rk);

Comment: Your application doesn't seem to offer anything with regards to concurrency. It even uses static variables. First design for concurrency, then come back if you fail. Read the books "effective Java" and "concurrency in practice". Oh, and 512 bit RSA keys are not enough. In general, you should not recreate RSA keys unless strictly required.

Comment: i don't have any backend to secure the application. so, i am using shared preferences for securing it. As shared preferences xml file can be edited from rooted device, i am using encryption. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: How are you storing the private key and public key to retrieve their generated values when the application restarts? You have not shown this code. If you have not taken it into account, then that is your problem. You need to save the keys

Comment: @pedrofb what you suspected is true. I am not storing the keys. when the application restarts it generates new random key pairs. Now, the key used for encryption is different and key used for decryption is different. As you suggested, i need to store the keys. But, can i store the keys in shared preferences? Because, if i store them in any global variables again  they will be cleared when app closes.

Comment: What is your android lowest target? Since android18 you should use AndroidKeyStore. If you need it I can post an example. For lower versions you can use shared preferences to serialize the keys, but with key size greater than 1024, they won't fit

Comment: @pedrofb my android lowest target is 15. please post the example. It will be really helpful.

Comment: An additional question, Why are you using an assymetric key pair and not a symmetric key to encrypt/decrypt?. For example using AES algorithm. Encryption and decryption are done in the same context, so using AES would be faster and simpler